# Why does superposing an infinite number of waves of different wavenumbers eliminate periodicity and may sometimes result in a localised wave?

Tags: waves, wavefunction, fourier-transform, superposition, signal-processing

I am studying how wave packets are defined in quantum mechanics, but I am finding it hard to intuitively understand why superposing an infinite number of waves of different wavenumbers $k$ may sometimes result in a wave packet that is localised.

I understand that constructive and destructive interference take place outside of the wave packet due to many different waves being superposed, resulting in an amplitude of 0. But whey does this not continue through the wave packet? So why does the wave packet exist at all?

[image: Demonstration of wave superposition]

In this picture there are many waves being superposed, but there are two points as you can see where the waves interfere constructively, and this results in a localised wave packet, and the more waves you superposed the more spread out these wave packets would be. But my question is: Why, when superposing  an infinite number of waves, there could still be one wave packet remaining?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier analysis and the Fourier transform?

Comment: Yes kind of, I have been learning about Fourier transforms with the hopes that it would answer my question, but I've not managed to relate the two

Comment: Wave packets are one solution to an ensemble of quanta, i.e. they can be used to describe an infinite repetition of the same experiment with one quantum. What is important is that you don't mistake that with the "localization" of a single quantum, which doesn't exist. Even more importantly, don't mistake them for the solutions of multi-quanta systems. Those systems don't make waves but an infinity of complex physical solutions. To cite MIT's Alan Addams: "Many electrons don't make waves. They make cheese.".

Comment: "Why" is not a meaningful question about math. Assumptions come with consequences. One can ask for a proof or for an elucidation of a proof or process. And to start to ask for that you have to find the assumptions, proof and/or process you are asking about including associated definitions. (Or an approximating sketch or metaphor.) PS That overlaying "superposing" of the graphs of the waves is not a graph of the "superposition" of the waves.

Comment: I feel some of your confusion might come from you making a wrong underlying assumption (that this happens simply because an infinite number of sinusoidal waves are added, and not *by design* - that is, there's a relationship between these waves that was set up on purpose that allows for the constructive interference to happen in this particular way).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a superposition of the form
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi j x}{L}\right)$$
Because I chose cosines, this function will automatically form a peak around $x=0$. This function will periodic with period $L$ (convince yourself of this). The period is $L$, because the smallest factor that is multiplied by $x$ in this sum is $2\pi/L$. If I make this factor smaller, by making $L$ larger for example, the wavelength/period of my final function will increase. Now imagine going to the continuum by taking an integral:
$$\psi(x)=\int\mathrm dk\, \phi(k)e^{ikx}$$
The value that is multiplied by $x$ is now $k$. Since $k$ can become arbitrarily small in this integral, the period of the resulting function will generally be infinite for an arbitrary function $\phi(k)$. This is why the wavepacket can be non-periodic.

On a related note, consider the identity
$$\int\mathrm dk\,e^{ikx}=2\pi\delta(x).$$
Although mathematicians would not like this identity, it tells a lot. It says that for $k\neq0$, integrating a rotating phase factor over all space gives zero$^\dagger$. This might motivate why the wavepacket tends to zero outside of its peak.

$\dagger$ This should be understood in a distributional sense. This means that you should only consider this as true when it appears inside an integral. This is just a disclaimer for the mathematicians

Comment: as a mathematician I can confirm I do not like this identity (but great answer, +1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am still slightly confused, since doesn't the superposition of waves also result with an infinite amplitude at x=0, because all the cosine functions will equal 1? Why is this allowed? Or should I think of wave packets being represented using Fourier transforms more as a general mathematical representation, as opposed to actually representing something physically?

Comment: @cookiecainsy If you let $n$ go to infinity, then yes. The example I gave will not converge to a wavepacket, but to something which has an infinite speak at evenly spaced intervals. It choose this example because you can see the period of the function relatively easily. More physical would be a gaussian wavepacket, although I don't know the shape of * actual * wavepackets in nature.

Answer (score 11):

Existing answer is good. I will add some remarks which I hope may further clarify.

1. The question is not essentially about quantum physics. It is about the use of Fourier series and Fourier transforms in any area of physics (or science more generally).
2. The question arises from an intuition that one should not be able to make a localised peak function from a sum of periodic functions. This is indeed true if there is a finite number of terms in the sum. So the question concerns an example of  a counter-intuitive fact involving infinity.
3. The physicist will also be concerned with another issue that might or might not bother a mathematician. Which of the functions here is 'physical' in the sense of 'a physical system might be accurately described by this function on its own'? The answer is that strictly periodic functions are unphysical because they involve an infinite number of repetitions, and this does not occur in the natural world. No water wave goes on forever, and neither does any sound wave or light wave or electronic oscillation. Also, in quantum physics no particle ever quite gets into a perfect momentum eigenstate. So when expressing a localised peak function as a sum of sins or cosines, we are doing a somewhat questionable thing: we are writing a physically possible function as a sum of physically impossible ones! We get away with this because there are any number of ways to show it will be ok. One way is to say we are not using strict sin functions that go on forever, we are just using functions that are like sin functions in a region extending well beyond the region of interest, and elsewhere they go smoothly to zero. Another way is to use strict sin function and simply trust the mathematics concerning infinity.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, could you also please explain why you cannot define a wave packet as an exponential function * sin wave, why is it even neccesary to take a superposition of waves in the first place?

Comment: see this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9127tutqxq

Comment: @cookiecainsy It's perfectly correct to define a wave packet as a (Gaussian) * (sin func) as you suggest. The function thus defined IS also a superposition of sin waves!  Each way of writing it has its uses. The Fourier analysis way can be useful when calculating reflection coefficients and things like that.

Comment: Can you explain why (Gaussian) * (sin func) is also a superposition. I thought the purpose of the Gaussain was to modulate the amplitude of the sin func, and nothing more?

Comment: @cookiecainsy - what Andrew Steane meant to say is that *any* wavefunction can be decomposed into a superposition of a bunch of sinusoidal waves of different frequencies and amplitudes. That is, there are two ways to look at any wave (no matter how wildly and unpredictably it wiggles) - you can look at the complicated shape of the wave itself, or you can look at it as the superposition of simple sine waves that form its "building blocks" (Fourier transform). There are mathematical ways to go back and forth between the two - you might want to do this when performing various analyses.